# Hive - TEMPORARY table use in INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE

Tags: hive, hiveql

I would like to use `TEMPORARY` table for intermediate query results.

is it possible to use TEMPORARY directly in `INSERT OVERWRITE TEMPORARY TABLE` command?

Should i use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TABLENAME AS SELECT .....` OR `INSERT OVERWRITE TEMPORARY TABLE` ?

Comment: Actually `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AS SELECT...` worked fine.

Comment: INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE  also should work (without temporary). It's no difference for insert statement temporary table or not temporary

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this: 
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp2 AS Select * from table_name;
here is the complete example.
http://dwgeek.com/apache-hive-temporary-tables-examples.html/